# PHP error Notice : Trying to get property of non-object in C:\code in line 303

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to run a PHP code and I am getting error for below code -

```
echo '<div class="container mt-4"><div class="row">'."\n";
            echo '<div class="col-md-4 mt-2">'."\n";
            echo '<h5>Basic figures</h5>'."\n";
            echo '<ul class="list-group">'."\n";

            echo "<li class='list-group-item'><i class='fa fa-database text-PMS'></i>&nbsp;Database:&nbsp;<span class='text-abc'>".$settingsProject['abc']['dbName']."</span></li>\n";

            $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/code/bin/db.php?function=getNumLocators&db='.$settingsProject['abc']['dbName']));
            echo "<li class='list-group-item'><i class='fa fa-hashtag text-PMS'></i>&nbsp;Num.locators:&nbsp;<span class='text-abc'>".$obj[0]->nLocators."</span></li>\n";
```

ERROR -

```
Notice
: Trying to get property of non-object in
C:\code\htdocs\Tools.php
on line
303
```

It was working fine till yesterday, changed nothing on code. But uninstalled few old version of MSSQL and reinstalled dotNet Framework...

The question looks duplicate, but it is not, I tried the solutions in other questions but it didn't work, so raised the question.

can someone please help me solve it ?

Comment: It means exactly what it says, probably this is the issue `$obj[0]->nLocators`  what is $obj, in other words do `var_export($obj)` before that error line.  As a quick test either remove or comment that out and see if the error goes away.  If so you'll have to back track and see what $obj is supposed to be and why its not that.  Without the piece of code where it is defined and set, I would be just guessing to say more.

Comment: AS it stands, your expecting `$obj` to be an array, with it's first element an object with a public property of `nLocators` those are a lot of assumptions to make in code, and you should be validating that before making these assumptions.

Comment: I dint change the code and it was working perfect till yesterday.. Why would it suddenly become invalid ?

Comment: Actually I see now, your getting it from JSON, this looks like a Database API, in that url, `function=getNumLocators&db=`   So you may have done something to the database you said `But uninstalled few old version of MSSQL`  IF that data was pulled from one of the Old versions of MSSQL, that could be 1 reason.  But I have no way to know what is at the endpoint of that url.  In this case, you should output the returned JSON, and see what is in there.

Comment: As a side note there are some security risks with using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.  Typically what I do for site URLS is make a defined constant for them in one central place and then use that constant in my code.  This gives you one place to change it in you application.  `if(!defined('SITE_URL')) define('SITE_URL', 'http://mysite-com/');`  And then you can do `file_get_contents(SITE_URL.'somepage?etc')` .  Its not impossible that a client can modify the value of headers sent to the server.   Headers that find their way into the `$_SERVER` array.  I don't know the level of risk of this

Comment: Its best to avoid it, I tried finding a link on SO for this issue, but I was too lazy to look to much.  Here is a related issues off of a Drupal support request, https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2221699  Just as an example, that these issues can and do happen in the real world.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks, will go through it and update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it using NP infront of DB Name, it was a DB Connectivity issue.

I go this error in Google Chrome inspect element -

```
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = -2146893022
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The target principal name is incorrect.
```

And I changed the code as under:

public function __construct($dbName) {

```
  $bd_server = 'NP:SQLSERVERNAME';


  try {
    $this->dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=" . $bd_server . ";Database=" .$dbName, NULL, NULL); 

    $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }   }
```

Just added  **NP:**  infront of server name, `$bd_server = 'NP:SQLSERVERNAME';`
You can also try **TCP:** `$bd_server = 'TCP:SQLSERVERNAME';`

What I noticed is that this will happen if you have uninstalled some component of MSSQL or DotNetFramework.

Hope this helps someone.